# error in Haversine formula and unable to get the average

Tags: excel, type-conversion

I have a column in excel with this format:

```
00:12:34
00:34:07
00:12:38
00:49:32
```

...

I need to convert this `hh:mm:ss` to `ss` but I can not.

[image]

I had tried to use custom formatting.
I have also tried multiplying the cell by 60, but it did not work.

[image]

I have also tried converting it to number but it still is not working.

can you please help me? :(

Comment: Multiply it by 86400 and format cell as number.